# Prevent from adding child data entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have this class structures.

```
public class Company :EntityBase
{

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name required-Cant be Blank")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " required-Cant be Blank")]
    public bool AnimalTesting { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentCompanyId")]
    public virtual ParentCompany ParentCompany { get; set; }

    public Company()
    {

    }


}

 public class ParentCompany : EntityBase
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Testing { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Company> Company { get; set; }
}
```

Now i am creating Company entity like this.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,AnimalTesting,ParentCompany")] Company company)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<ParentCompany> parents = (List<ParentCompany>)unitOfWork.ParentCompanyRepository.List
                (o => o.Name == company.ParentCompany.Name);


            if (parents.Count==0)
            {
               unitOfWork.ParentCompanyRepository.Add(company.ParentCompany);
               unitOfWork.CompanyRepository.Add(company);
            }
            else
            {
                IMyContext context;
                context = unitOfWork.GetDbContext<VeganDbContext>();
                context.Entry(company.ParentCompany).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                context.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Added;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(company);
    }
```

When i want to add company with the existing ParentCompany in database, program goes to else brackets. Now i am getting error but this is ok it say that i can't add the same value that exist currently in database.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Company_dbo.ParentCompany_ParentCategoryId". The conflict
>   occurred in database
>   "ASPNET_VEGAN_20150428012206_c73db9e12d424dfd80e198ac36a739cf", table
>   "dbo.ParentCompany", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

But :) Now there is my point.
I want to add the existing fields in database to my company but i dont want to add the same ParentCompany to database.

Any ideas how to achieve my point ?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm i found solution :D

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,AnimalTesting,ParentCompany")] Company company)
    {
        List<Company> ExistCompany = (List<Company>)unitOfWork.CompanyRepository.List
                (o => o.Name == company.Name);

        if (ModelState.IsValid && ExistCompany.Count==0)
        {
            List<ParentCompany> Parents = (List<ParentCompany>)unitOfWork.ParentCompanyRepository.List
                (o => o.Name == company.ParentCompany.Name);


            if (Parents.Count==0)
            {
               unitOfWork.ParentCompanyRepository.Add(company.ParentCompany);
               unitOfWork.CompanyRepository.Add(company);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (ParentCompany p in Parents)
                {
                    company.ParentCompany = p;
                    break;
                }
                IMyContext context;
                context = unitOfWork.GetDbContext<VeganDbContext>();
                context.Entry(company.ParentCompany).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                context.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Added;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        if(ExistCompany.Count!=0)
           ViewBag.ExistCompany = "Company with that name exist ";

        return View(company);
    }
```